# Connection between WindowGroup and ImmersiveSpace Entity on visionOS

Tags: position, visionos, windowgroup

I would like to replicate the following behavior of the Apple Mindfulness app on visionOS: the 3D object is behind the window, and when the window is moved, the object follows the window's position. Once the session starts, the object stays in the same position.

[image: visionOS mindfulness app]

It looks like the object is in the immersive space. I'm not sure if it's in the immersion space from the beginning, but it's almost certainly there after the session starts. So, it looks like there is a connection between the WindowGroup's position and the object.

It seems that it's not possible to get the position of the window, so I have no clue how Apple achieved such behavior. I just hope they are not using a private API, and you'll be able to help me. Thank you in advance!